# 2.2 B2B - Error when editing company

Tags: magento2.2, b2b

When updating a company in the Magento Admin, I am seeing this error:

`No company admin website ID is specified in request.`

When that error occurs, I am redirected to the **New Company** form. Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

Comment: This error indicates that website_id is not set. Does the Company Admin -> Website field have a value? Does the Company Admin -> Email field reference an existing customer?

Comment: @ddavidn The company is assigned to a Web site. I tried changing the Admin E-mail, but I am still receiving this error when I save the company.

Comment: I'm wondering about the actual customer account for the company admin, is it existing or trying to create a new one (default behavior if admin email does not exist as a customer object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had the time to return to this task and debug it properly using xDebug, and found the issue:

A preference for the `Save` Controller had been created by a previous developer which was missing `CustomerInterface::WEBSITE_ID` from the `$allFormFields` array in the `extractData()` method. ‍♂️

Comment: I am facing issue like "could not save company" after saving it. Have you any idea?